# What exactly does "*=" mean in C programming?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I've been looking at some RobotC code, which is pretty similar to C (and I don't have enough reputation to make a new RobotC tag), and I came across the
*= operator. I've googled it quite a bit, but all I can get that it is a bitwise operator in C. Nobody seems to say exactly what it does, however and I'd appreciate it if you guys can help.

```
rot *= 5;
```

Here's the code in which I found it. All the function does is reorient the robot to always face North.

```
//Turns back to North
void TurnStraight(int cdegree) //cdegree is the sensor value read by the compass sensor
{
  int rot = cdegree % 360;
  int mot = 1;
  //stop when the NXT facing North
  if (cdegree == 0){
     return;
  }
  //reset the encoders value to avoid overflaow
   clear_motor_encoders();

   if (cdegree > 180 && cdegree < 360){
      rot = 360 - rot;
      mot = 0;
   }

   rot *= 5;  // ratio between the circumference of the tire to the circumference of the     rotation circle around itself
   switch (mot){
     case 1:
     moveTo(rot/2,1);
     break;
     case 0:
     moveTo(rot/2,-1);
     break;
     case -1:
     moveTo(rot,1);
     break;
   }
}


void clear_motor_encoders()
{
   nMotorEncoder[motorA] = 0;
}

void moveTo(int rot, int direction)
{
   nSyncedMotors = synchAC;
   nSyncedTurnRatio = -100;
   nMotorEncoderTarget[motorA] = rot;
   motor[motorA] = direction * 50;
   while (nMotorRunState[motorA] != runStateIdle) ;
   motor[motorA] = 0;

}
```

This is not my code of course, I would just like to know how it works.

Comment: It may be hard to search Google for `*=`, but "C operators" would have gotten you easily to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators)

Comment: Check out Steve Summit's ["Introductory C programming"](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/cclass.html), dated but very relevant. And before you start asking why your program crashes due to obvious pointer problems, read and _understand_ Ted Jensen's ["A tutorial on pointers and arrays in C"](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm) (also quite dated, but essential).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's equivalent to:

```
rot = rot * 5;
```

It's part of a family of operators called 'compound assignment' operators. You can see the full list of them here: [Compound Assignment Operators (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Compound_assignment_operators)

Note that `*=` isn't a bitwise operator, because `*` isn't. But some compound operators are bitwise - for example, the `&=` operator is bitwise, since `&` is.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight oh wow it never occurred to me that you can use *= just like += Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As in most programming languages, this is a short form for `var = var * 5`.

So other examples `var += 3` equals a statement of `var = var + 3`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the multiply-assign operator. It means the same thing as

```
rot = rot * 5;
```

This is not a bitwise operator, although there are bitwise operators of the same kind:

- `&=` - and-assign,
- `|=` - or-assign,
- `^=` - xor-assign.

Other operators of the family include `+=`, `-=`, `/=`, and `%=`.

Answer (score 1):

If you understand the code

```
rot += 5;
```

you should understand

```
rot *= 5;
```

Instead of adding 5 to rot, you are multiplying it by 5.